# Do I need to release SystemSoundID if I have ARC on?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, avfoundation, audiotoolbox

Question is in the title: "Do I need to release SystemSoundID if I have ARC on?" Here is my Code:

```
NSURL *pathURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
SystemSoundID soundid;
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge_retained CFURLRef)pathURL, &soundid);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundid);
```

And if so, when do I release it? (I don't have a dealloc method because I'm using a static method and that cannot be changed)

Also, is this currently the best way to play a sound effect I heard this framework is now deprecated.

THANKS!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you do need to release it. ARC only concerns itself with Obj-C objects, and a `SystemSoundID` is not an obj-c object. At some point you do need to call `AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID()` on your `SystemSoundID` value. You could do this with a system sound completion routine (using `AudioServicesAddSystemSoundCompletion()`).

As for what sergio is talking about, you're leaking the `pathURL` object. You've used `__bridge_retained`, which transfers ownership of the object to CoreFoundation. You should probably just change that to `(__bridge CFURLRef)pathURL`, which will not transfer ownership. The AudioServices API will retain the object as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

According to [clang ref](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#objects.operands.casts)

> (__bridge_retained T) op casts the operand, which must have retainable object pointer type, to the destination type, which must be a non-retainable pointer type. ARC retains the value, subject to the usual optimizations on local values, and the recipient is responsible for balancing that +1.

Thus, you need to do the release.

In other words, what happens in the bridge cast is that the ownership of `pathURL` is passe over to CF, and then out of ARC scope.

Comment: Good point, but you're actually talking about the `pathURL` parameter. Instead of releasing this, it should just be a `__bridge` cast.